# Continuity of partial derivatives and continuity of the function

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity

Let $f: \mathbb{R^2} \to \mathbb{R}$ a function which partial derivatives exist near a point P. Suppose one of the partial derivatives is continous in P. Is this enough for the function to be countinous in P? I have tried to prove it but I did't suceeded. Can you give me a hint on how to prove it, or the entire proof?

Comment: For a proof see Apostol's Mathematical Analysis, second edition (Theorem-$12.11$)

Comment: Ok! Thanks! Can I find this book online?

Comment: I think so.But any departmental library should have this book.